# Apache POI powerpoint, image filename incorrect

Tags: apache-poi, powerpoint

I would like to get the name of the images of my powerpoint with Apache POI, but it is not correct, it is always "image1.jpeg" (or a different number)

```js
ppt.getPictureData().forEach(xslfPictureData - > {
  String filename = xslfPictureData.getFileName();
});
```

To customize the name of the images I go to the "selection panel".
[custom image name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lnL5y.png)

Isn't there a way to get an image name or id?

Comment: the file name that you get from xslfPictureData.getFileName() is based on the filename as it appears in the pptx file - pptx is basically a zip file - image1 is typically the name of the file - are you sure that your custom image name is really being applied?

Answer (score 1):

`XMLSlideShow.getPictureData` gets all embedded pictures from slide show. But to show those pictures on the slides, they are placed in picture shapes on the slide.

What your linked image shows is the name of the picture shape on the slide. This is not the same as the file name of the embedded picture file. File names of the embedded picture files are `image1.*`, `image2.*`, .... `image[n].*`. The name of the picture shape on the slide can be customised.

To get those `XSLFPictureShape`s one needs traversing the shapes of the slides and check whether there are `XSLFPictureShape`s.

Until now, `apache poi` does not provide a method to get the name from `XSLFPictureShape`. So one needs using the underlying `CT`-Objects to get the name if needed.

Following complete example shows this.

```java
import java.io.FileInputStream;

import org.apache.poi.xslf.usermodel.*;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.drawingml.x2006.main.*;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.presentationml.x2006.main.*;

public class PPTXGetPictureShapes {
        
 static String getName(XSLFPictureShape pictureShape) {
  String name = null;
  org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlObject xmlObject = pictureShape.getXmlObject();
  if (xmlObject instanceof CTPicture) {
   CTPicture ctPicture = (CTPicture)xmlObject;
   CTPictureNonVisual nvSpPr = ctPicture.getNvPicPr();
   if (nvSpPr != null) {
    CTNonVisualDrawingProps cnv = nvSpPr.getCNvPr();
    if (cnv != null) {
     name = cnv.getName();
    }
   }
  }      
  return name;
 }
      
 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
     
  XSLFSlideShowFactory factory = new XSLFSlideShowFactory();
  XMLSlideShow slideShow = factory.create(new FileInputStream("./PPTXPresentation.pptx"));
  
  for (XSLFSlide slide : slideShow.getSlides()) {
   System.out.println(slide);        
   for (XSLFShape shape : slide.getShapes()) {
    System.out.println(shape); 
    
    if (shape instanceof XSLFPictureShape) {
     XSLFPictureShape pictureShape = (XSLFPictureShape)shape;
     String pictureShapeName = getName(pictureShape);
     System.out.println(pictureShapeName); 
    }
    
   }       
  }
 }
}
```

Btw.: If you have the [XSLFPictureShape](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/xslf/usermodel/XSLFPictureShape.html), you also can get the `XSLFPictureData` from this to get the byte data of the embedded picture. So there is no need for `XMLSlideShow.getPictureData`.